# c# search and replace

Tags: c#, php, expression

I'm a beginner in C#.
I'm trying to make a small tool for search&replace

I have this input:

```
"name"  => "Hello world",
```

I want this output:

```
'name'   =>__( 'Hello world','$Variable'),
```

This is my try:

```
 private string ReplaceBackgroundDirection(string Source)
        {
Source = Source.Replace("name", "name");
Source = Source.Replace("=>"+"", "=> __(");
```

Comment: I don't get your question please try to define what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to return the replaced string:

```
private string ReplaceBackgroundDirection(string Source)
 {

    return Source.Replace("\"", "'").Replace("=>","=>__(") + "'$Variable'),";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @celerno :) but why i get Negative rating :(

Comment: The spelling and grammar on your question needs a lot of improvement. And I'm guessing that English speakers find hard to understand what you wanted to say. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will not be a waste of time.

Comment: @celerno Thank you very much Respect you